# Convenient way of inserting values to Cassandra with Phantom

Tags: scala, phantom-dsl

Does anyone know of a convenient way of inserting values to Cassandra via phatom-dsl? Currently I'm doing this:

```
case class Entry(id: UUID, firstName: String, lastName: String)

sealed class EntryTable extends CassandraTable[EntryTable, Entry] {
  override val tableName = "entries"
  object id extends UUIDColumn(this) with Index[UUID]
  object firstName extends StringColumn(this)
  object lastName extends StringColumn(this)

  override def fromRow(r: dsl.Row): Entry = {
    Entry(id(r), firstName(r), firstName(r))
  }
}

object EntryTable extends EntryTable {
   private val connector = CassandraConnector.apply(Set(InetAddress.getByName("localhost")))
   implicit val keySpace = KeySpace("keyspace")

   def insert(e: Entry) = {
     connector.withSessionDo(implicit session => {
       insert().value(_.id, e.id)).value(_.firstName, e.firstName).value(_.lastName, e.lastName).future()
     }
   }
}
```

But I would like to do:

```
def insert(e: Entry) = {
  connector.withSessionDo(implicit session => {
    insert().value(e).future()
  }
}
```

Which would be way more convenient when the case class has many fields. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the API slightly wrong and we are in the process of publishing multiple tutorials to make the "new" way public. In the mean time, a basic version of it is available [here](http://slides.com/flavalex/upgrading-to-phantom-1-10-x#/) and [this branch](https://github.com/websudos/phantom-activator-template/tree/feature/phantom_upgrade) in the activator template is also describing everything you need to know.

Specifically, the way to insert records is described [here](https://github.com/websudos/phantom/blob/develop/phantom-dsl/src/test/scala/com/websudos/phantom/tables/TestTable.scala#L74).